Handling Fetch API Errors in JavaScript: Displaying API Response in a Popup
I'm working on a payment integration using the Payway API in a Symfony application with Twig templates. When I submit expired credit card details, the API correctly returns a JSON response indicating the error. However, instead of showing a popup with the error message, the full JSON response is displayed directly on the page.
Here is the JSON response from the API when the card is expired:
json
Copy code
{
    "error": "Payment failed",
    "details": {
        "transactionId": 3825557492,
        "receiptNumber": "3825557492",
        "status": "declined",
        "responseCode": "54",
        "responseText": "Expired card",
        "transactionType": "payment",
        "customerNumber": "DUMMYCUSTOMER123",
        "customerName": "2566",
        "orderNumber": "5240000123-061223",
        "currency": "aud",
        "principalAmount": 1000,
        "surchargeAmount": 12,
        "paymentAmount": 1012,
        "paymentMethod": "creditCard",
        "creditCard": {
            "cardNumber": "456471...012",
            "expiryDateMonth": "02",
            "expiryDateYear": "25",
            "cardScheme": "visa",
            "cardType": "credit",
            "cardholderName": "2566",
            "panType": "fpan"
        },
        "merchant": {
            "merchantId": "TEST",
            "merchantName": "Test Merchant",
            "links": [
                {
                    "rel": "self",
                    "href": "https://api.payway.com.au/rest/v1/merchants/TEST"
                }
            ]
        },
        "transactionDateTime": "25 Jul 2024 05:11 AEST",
        "settlementDate": "25 Jul 2024",
        "declinedDate": "25 Jul 2024",
        "customerIpAddress": "127.0.0.1",
        "isVoidable": false,
        "isRefundable": false,
        "links": [
            {
                "rel": "self",
                "href": "https://api.payway.com.au/rest/v1/transactions/3825557492"
            }
        ]
    }
}

Goal:
I want to display a popup with the specific error message (e.g., "Expired card") when the payment fails, instead of navigating to a new page with the full JSON response.
Code:
Here is my JavaScript code that handles the form submission and fetch request:
class ResponseError extends Error {
    constructor(message, response) {
        super(message);
        this.response = response;
    }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    const creditCardForm = document.getElementById('creditCardForm');
    const hiddenForm = document.getElementById('hiddenForm');
    const submitButton = document.getElementById('submitButton');

    creditCardForm.addEventListener('submit', async function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        // Disable the submit button to prevent multiple submissions
        submitButton.disabled = true;
        submitButton.innerText = 'Processing...';

        const formData = new FormData(creditCardForm);

        try {
            const response = await fetch(creditCardForm.action, {
                method: 'POST',
                body: formData
            });

            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new ResponseError('Failed to fetch', response);
            }

            const data = await response.json();

            if (data.singleUseTokenId) {
                document.getElementById('token').value = data.singleUseTokenId;
                hiddenForm.submit();
            } else {
                alert('Unable to generate token. Please try again.');
                submitButton.disabled = false;
                submitButton.innerText = 'Submit';
            }
        } catch (error) {
            if (error instanceof ResponseError) {
                const errorData = await error.response.json();
                alert(`Error: ${errorData.details.responseText || 'Unknown error'}`);
            } else {
                console.error('Error:', error);
                alert('An unexpected error occurred. Please try again.');
            }
            submitButton.disabled = false;
            submitButton.innerText = 'Submit';
        }
    });
});

this is the controller method for this part :
  public function generateSingleUseToken(Request $request, int $id, HttpClientInterface $client, InvoiceRepository $invoiceRepository): JsonResponse
    {
        $cardNumber = $request->request->get('cardNumber');
        $expiryDateMonth = $request->request->get('expiryDateMonth');
        $expiryDateYear = $request->request->get('expiryDateYear');
        $cvn = $request->request->get('cvn');
        $cardholderName = $request->request->get('cardholderName');

        try {
            $response = $client->request('POST', $_ENV['PAYWAY_BASE_URL'] . '/single-use-tokens', [
                'headers' => [
                    'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . base64_encode($_ENV['PAYWAY_PUBLISHABLE_KEY'] . ':'),
                    'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                ],
                'body' => http_build_query([
                    'paymentMethod' => 'creditCard',
                    'cardNumber' => $cardNumber,
                    'expiryDateMonth' => $expiryDateMonth,
                    'expiryDateYear' => $expiryDateYear,
                    'cvn' => $cvn,
                    'cardholderName' => $cardholderName
                ]),
            ]);

            $data = $response->toArray(false);

            if (!isset($data['singleUseTokenId'])) {
                return new JsonResponse($data, 400);
            }

            return new JsonResponse(['singleUseTokenId' => $data['singleUseTokenId']]);

        } catch (HttpExceptionInterface $e) {
            $responseContent = $e->getResponse()->getContent(false);
            $responseData = json_decode($responseContent, true);
            return new JsonResponse($responseData, $e->getStatusCode());
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return new JsonResponse(['error' => 'An error occurred.', 'message' => $e->getMessage()], 500);
        }

Problem:
Despite trying to handle the errors correctly, I keep getting the full JSON response displayed directly instead of the tailored error message. What am I missing or doing wrong here? How can I ensure that the specific error message (like "Expired card") is displayed in a popup?

Have you checked the browser's console for any javascript errors? Possibly an error is preventing the submit handler from intercepting the form submission, and it's just posting back normally instead. That would be a likely explanation for why you just get the raw json on the screen in a new page

yes I received this
{data: Array(4), links: Array(1)}
data
:
Array(4)
0
:
{fieldName: 'cardNumber', message: 'Too short.  Please enter at least 13 characters.', fieldValue: 'ddd'}
1
:
{fieldName: 'cvn', message: 'Too short.  Please enter at least 3 characters.', fieldValue: ''}
2
:
{fieldName: 'expiryDateMonth', message: 'Invalid expiry date.', fieldValue: ''}
3
:
{fieldName: 'expiryDateYear', message: 'Invalid number.', fieldValue: '**'}
length
:
4
[[Prototype]]
:
Array(0)
links
:

Hm, that doesn't seem to be an error message, but rather some logged information maybe from some other JS code that you haven't shown us? Or does it come from one of the lines in there? Can you tell us which line generated the message (I think the developer tools should point you to it, if you're unsure) And is that all you see? None of that is a system-generated JS error which would stop it executing
